# Bash: read a value from a file, increment and write to file in single command

Tags: linux, bash

In the course of a deployment process i Need to:

1) read a numeric value from http://example.com/version.txt (version.txt only contains an integer as string indicating the version)

2) convert to integer and increment it by 1

3) write it to a local file `version.txt` that does not exist (create and write)

Can this be accomplished in a single command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a command line can also contain a [list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html), you can put an entire shell script on a command line.

In your case you want: 1. `curl`, 2. `expr`, an [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.htm), 3. an [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) or similar. This amounts to:

```
n=$(curl http://example.com/version.txt)
m=$(( n + 1 ))
echo $m > version.txt
```

or on one line:

```
echo $(($(curl http://example.com/version.txt) + 1) >version.txt
```

Comment: Note that this has no error checking; if there's a problem fetching the file, you may get invalid (or no) output. If this matters in your application, you may need to check validity *before* redirecting into the file.